# Как в EditText отделить разряды?

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText используется для вывода больших чисел.
Как сделать отделение каждых трех разрядов числа пробелом?
Например 9 999 999

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать это с помощью  `TextWatcher`.

Например, для форматирования номера телефона можно использовать готовый класс `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`, реализующий интерфейс `TextWatcher`:

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
inputField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

В итоге вводимый текст +375298076740 будет выглядеть как

> +375 29 807-67-40

Если же Вам нужно выводить текст группами именно по три символа, можете воспользоваться следующим классом:

```
public class OwnWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    // Change this to what you want... ' ', '-' etc..
    private static final char space = ' ';

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Remove spacing char
        if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 4) == 0) {
            final char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
            if (space == c) {
                s.delete(s.length() - 1, s.length());
            }
        }
        // Insert char where needed.
        if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 4) == 0) {
            char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
            // Only if its a digit where there should be a space we insert a space
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(s.toString(), String.valueOf(space)).length <= 3) {
                s.insert(s.length() - 1, String.valueOf(space));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И присвойте его конкретному полю:

```
inputField.addTextChangedListener(new OwnWatcher());
```

Вывод получится как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выглядит очень хорошо и просто, но почему то не работает =(
Класс создал такой же. В фрагменте в onCreateView присвоил слушатель. Но не срабатывает.

Comment: А какие ошибки выдаёт?

Comment: Без ошибок, просто текст как обычно остается

Comment: Может ссылку на проект положить?

Answer (score 2):

Переопределить метод onDraw.

В нем сделать логику, которая будет добавлять/удалять пробел.

Возможно, есть лучше способы реализовать это.