# Динамическая проверка записанного в EditText

Tags: android

Вопрос такой: реально ли как-то отслеживать динамично записанные данные в EditText в androi? К примеру, у меня есть данные о максимальном и минимальном значении числа, необходимо проверить, не выпадает ли значение, введённое пользователем, из заданных границ (либо в процессе набора, либо по переключению на следующих элемент лайаута) и, если число не входит в границы, заменить введённое число.
Искал в интернете, но попадаюсь лишь на примеры проверки во время нажатия кнопки, что не подходит, т.к. много вкладок и много EditText'ов.
За программирование андроида сел буквально вот-вот, так что сильно тапочками не бейте)
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На `EditText` можно повесить слушатель ввода, в котором обрабатывать ввод, как, собственно, в процессе, так и по его завершении:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

            // действия, когда вводится какой то текст
            // s - то, что вводится, для преобразования в строку - s.toString()
            }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { 

        // действия после того, как что то введено
        // editable - то, что введено. В строку - editable.toString()
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // действия перед тем, как что то введено
        }
});
```

Примеры:

[валидация на ведущий ноль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573434/177345) при вводе.

проверка [на пустое поле ввода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649713/177345).

[Отделение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554280/177345) разрядов числа пробелом

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно то что нужно:

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

public interface OnMinMaxExcessListener {

    void onMinExceeded(float min, float input);

    void onMaxExceeded(float max, float input);

}

private OnMinMaxExcessListener mExcessListener;

private float min, max;


public InputFilterMinMax(float pMin, float pMax, OnMinMaxExcessListener pExcessListener) {
    min = pMin;
    max = pMax;
    mExcessListener = pExcessListener;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    float input = Utils.parseFloat(dest.toString() + source.toString());
    if (isInRange(min, max, input)) {
        return source;
    } else {

        if (mExcessListener != null) {
            if (input < min) mExcessListener.onMinExceeded(min, input);
            if (input > max) mExcessListener.onMaxExceeded(max, input);
        }

        if (Math.log10(input) + 1 < Math.log10(min) + 1) return source;
        else return Float.toString(min);
    }
}

private boolean isInRange(float a, float b, float c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
} 
}

public static float parseFloat(String value) {
    return value == null || value.isEmpty() ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.'));
}
```